# command-line way to set up routing on mac and linux

Tags: linux, networking, macos, debian, routing

My setup:

- PC: debian 9, kernel 4.9.x

  - eth1, 10 Gbit ethernet (PC <-> MAC)
- MAC: mojave 10.14.1

  - en0, 1 Gbit ethernet (MAC <-> internet)
  - en6, 10 Gbit via thunderbolt 3 (MAC <-> PC)

My goals are:

- on MAC, have access to internet (via en0)
- on MAC, have access to PC (via en6)
- on MAC, share internet with PC (via en6)

Both on MAC and PC, I would like to setup networking and routing via command line, currently I have:

- on PC

```
ifconfig eth1 inet 192.168.10.20 netmask 255.255.255.0

ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev eth1
```

- on MAC

```
ifconfig en0 inet 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig en6 inet 192.168.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0

sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1
route -n change -net 192.168.10.0/24 -interface en6
```

Any hints how to achieve described goals?

Comment: What is the problem? What does work so far? What doesn't? Have you tried to ping some host? What was the result?

Comment: MAC have access to internet and I am able to communicate between PC and MAC via 10 Gbit ethernet, but I am not sure how to share internet from MAC to PC.

Comment: You must look for [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). I don't know how to do this on MacOS.

Comment: Maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/192089 is of help.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I managed to get it working using ui configurators... will try to figure out later how to get this done via command line.